# Custom ReSharper TODO-item

Tags: regex, resharper

I'm trying to add a new filter for to-do items in `ReSharper v10`.
To indicate a to-do item I add the following to the code

> // TODO @[DEVNAME] - ...

where `DEVNAME` is the shortcut for the developer who should fix the described issue. However, I get totally stuck in creating a todo-filter for only my issues.

I tried something like `(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>TODO @[KIKE])(\W|$)(.*)` or `(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>TODO)(\W|$)(.*) @[KIKE]` but nothing is working.

Comment: change the `@[KIKE]` to `@\[KIKE\]` - square brackets have a special meaning in regex so you need to escape them

Comment: Tried `(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>TODO @\[KIKE\])(\W|$)(.*)` and `(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>TODO)(\W|$)(.*) @\[KIKE\]` but still not working. Maybe the space is an issue?

Comment: [works on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mD4sS8/1) - maybe it's a resharper thing. Hopefully someone else will be able to help you :)

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio seems to have the issue fixed. `(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>TODO @\[KIKE\])(\W|$)(.*)` is working as expected. You can create an answer that I can accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Regular Expressions, square brackets have a special meaning, so to use them literally, you have to escape them with a `\` character.

Therefore, the correct expression would be:

```
(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>TODO @\[KIKE\])(\W|$)(.*)
```

to match:

> // TODO @[KIKE] - ...

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD4sS8/1)

If you have trouble, it is worth restarting Visual Studio.

Without escaping the square brackets, the `(?<TAG>TODO @[KIKE])` part of the expression was saying

- match "TODO @"
- followed by *one* occurrence of any of these characters - K or I or E